# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\errors\report.php'

Tags: magento-1.9, php

i just copied working folders and files from Ubuntu to windows and whenever i try run the project am getting error like:

> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required 'D:\xampp\htdocs\geedel\errors\report.php' (include_path='D:\xampp\htdocs\geedel\app\code\local;D:\xampp\htdocs\geedel\app\code\community;D:\xampp\htdocs\geedel\app\code\core;D:\xampp\htdocs\geedel\lib;D:\xampp\php\PEAR') in D:\xampp\htdocs\geedel\app\Mage.php on line 925.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fundamentals for debugging a Magento store](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store)

Answer (score 3):

Please check if you have a folder named `errors` on your magento root and whether there is a php file named `report.php` (probably someone had added entire errors folder to the gitignore or something? Just guessing).

Answer (score 1):

You're running into an error during execution which is generating a report.  While running in "production" mode, errors will not be shown on screen; instead, they're logged to files under `var/reports/` and a reference to that report number is shown to the user in the output of `report.php`.

It appears that you're missing the required `errors` folder which will provide the logging and the error display.  There are two ways to fix this:

1. Copy the missing `errors` folder to your new installation
2. Force Magento into "developer" mode and show the errors on screen.

To force Magento into developer mode you can do one of two things:

#### Set Environment Variable and Force Developer Mode

In your virtual host settings, you can specify the environment variable `MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE` and set its value to anything you want.  As long as it's set, Magento will use developer mode and show you the errors on screen.

To set it in nginx, you can include the line below in your `\.php$` block:

```
fastcgi_param MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1
```

For Apache, you would add this to your virtual host definition

```
SetEnv MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE 1
```

#### Modify `index.php` and force Developer Mode

Alternatively, if you want a quick fix and it's only temporary, you can edit `index.php` at the root of the Magento installation and on line 69 you should see:

```
 if (isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
     Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
 }
```

Just change that `if` statement to be `true` and you'll be in developer mode.  For example:

```
if (true || isset($_SERVER['MAGE_IS_DEVELOPER_MODE'])) {
```